# Run standalone Completable on background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android, android-thread

I am trying to create a completable and run it on background thread but it's not calling `Action`'s `run()` when I am subscribing on `Schedulers.io()`

Basically I want to do following through RxAndroid:

```
     Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doSomething();
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

Using RxAndroid I am doing following:

```
   Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            doSomething();
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

It's `run()` method is not getting called if I do `Schedulers.io()`, but it gets called if I do `subscribe()`.

I am unable to find why it's running when I subscribe for `Schedulers.io()`.

Answer (score 10):

Stream would executed only if it has been subscribed. It means, that your completable should be subscribed in order `run()` method to be executed. `subscribeOn()` does **not** subscribe to the stream, it just tells **on which thread** to subscribe.

In your example just adding `subscribe()` to the end would initiate `run()` method to be called:

```
    Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            doSomething();
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(...);
```